# Disable caching of a single file with try_files directive

Tags: angular, nginx

I'm serving Angular 2 application with nginx using location section this way:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```

try_files directive tries to find the requested uri in root directory and if it fails to find one it simply returns index.html

How to disable caching of index.html file?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Found a solution using nginx named locations:

```
location = / {
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    expires 0;
    try_files /index.html =404;
}

location / {
    gzip_static on;
    try_files $uri @index;
}

location @index {
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    expires 0;
    try_files /index.html =404;
}
```

Comment: This is the right solution

The solution fro Dmitry will only work for the canonical url, if the user access from a url like /foo/, it will serve the index.html, but with no expires..

Comment: @Rem For angular it didn't work for me, basically, I have disabled global caching and it works but when I am trying same for a single file like the index.html then it not working do you have any other idea?

Comment: it works perfectly fine (except for URL ending literally with `/index.html`), just don't put `index` directive in `location /`

Comment: Why do we need the first block? Isn't enough just the second and third?

Answer (score 23):

Thanks for a great answer Rem!  As He Shiming points out with the accepted solution the caching headers don't get added when visiting the root e.g. www.example.com/, but do get added when visiting any deep link, e.g. www.example.com/some/path.

After a lot of digging I believe this is because of the default behaviour of the ngnix module [ngx_http_index_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html), it includes index.html by default so when visiting the root /, the first location block's rules are satisfied, and index.html gets served without the cache control headers.  The workaround I used was to include an index directive without specifying index.html in the first location block, forcing the root / to be served from the second location block.

I also had another problem, I included a root directive in the first location block which broke deep links and is also a [bad idea](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#root-inside-location-block).  I moved the root directive to the server level.

Hope this helps, this is my solution...

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;
  root   /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location / {
    add_header X-debug-whats-going-on 1;
    index do-not-use-me.html;
    try_files $uri @index;                 
  }

  location @index {
    add_header X-debug-whats-going-on 2;
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    expires 0;
    try_files /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

I've included debug headers to help make it absolutely clear what location block is serving what content.  It's also worth noting the [unintuitive behaviour of the add_header directive](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/be-very-careful-with-your-add_header-in-nginx), essential reading if you also intend to add headers to all requests outside of a location block.

Comment: props for the debug headers, showing a way to debug this as well as a solution. Teach a man to fish and all...

Comment: This solution will not cover a case where the user requests /index.html directly.

Comment: The question is around support for an Angular website where /index.html should never be directly requested.  This also works well for me for a React website.

Comment: Thanks for including a mention to the confusing add_header behaviour. Saved me a headache trying to figure out why my CSP had stopped working!

Comment: why not just remove the `index` directive from `location /` entirely?

Comment: @adam if you remove the index directive, it defaults to the default index.html value and nothing works.  So overriding the default is super important.

Answer (score 21):

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location = /index.html {
  expires -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How do you think which solution is more efficient?

Comment: This answer is better than both Rem's and Simon Ness's, since it will also cover a case where the user requests /index.html directly.

Comment: ERROR: Pre-processing of application version app-aa94-200816_122944 has failed.
ERROR: Some application versions failed to process. Unable to continue deployment

Answer (score 7):

I got the following setup working for my Angular apps, includes changes to index.html and nginx configuration:

index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

nginx.conf

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location ~ \.html$ {
  add_header Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
  add_header Expires "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT";
  add_header Pragma no-cache;
}
```

Works both when user navigates to "site.com" and "site.com/some/url" or "site.com/#/login".
The "index.html" changes are to be on the safe side mainly.

Comment: It stops app working when I am using the second location block I have the same configuration but don't know why it is not blessing me.
Do I need any other setting?

Answer (score 7):

You can use content-type mapping (should do the job for SPA with one `.html` file):

```
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch; # means no-cache
}

server {
  expires $expires;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to be safe :)

```
location = /index.html {
    add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
    expires off;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it by adding a couple of lines in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` in the `nginx:stable-alpine` docker:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        add_header Cache-Control 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'; # <-- added this
        expires 0; # <-- added this
    }
}
```

Caching is disabled for both `/` and `/index.html` paths.

Answer (score 0):

Found another solution.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
    add_header Pragma "no-cache";
    add_header Expires 0;
}

# Cache static files
location ~* \.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$ {
    expires 30d;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

This works fine.

The accepted solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/41632171/9272654 Doesn't work on the route refresh but this solution works fine.