How to solve Cache problem in angular application
I'm facing an issue regarding cache in browser. Whenever I'm deploying new Angular UI the cache of Older remains untill I clear the browser cache manually.
How can I solve this
Thanks in advance for help
Need a solution to solve this problem.

you can hard refresh, caching is done to improve the performance of the website

If you are not using SSR, you can disable caching for the index.html file. It is very small, so performance should not be a big deal. If you are using output hashing, the new UI should load right after deployment. Which web server technology do you use? Nginx / IIS / Apache? Then we can help you setting up the right config.

I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question. Angular does output hashing by default which takes care of caching the CSS and JS files. I think this is only about the index.html, where you cannot apply output hashing via query params.

@JSONDerulo so, it's not about controlling the browser cache. OP simply wants to control the browser cache?

@VLAZ it is, but the offered solutions are more about the JS and CSS files and will not work for the index.html file, which I strongly believe is the only thing here where caching needs to be adjusted.

@JSONDerulo setting the cache control headers (Cache-Control, If-Modified-Since, ETag, etc.) affect all resources: JS, CSS, but also images, fonts, as well as HTML files. But OK, let's assume that's not what's asked here. I am fairly confident that "how do I do cache busting (for one file)" is not a new and unique problem to solve. After all, this has only been an issue in web development for the last ~30 years or so. Feel free to find a better duplicate.

@VLAZ agreed. I found another question where it's specifically about the index.html.

@JSONDerulo I use Nginx

@AtharvaZade see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41631399
